# Javascript based spell-checkers for web applications

Tags: javascript, requirements, spell-checking

I have just received a requirement to implement spell checking on a web application that we are creating.  I know all about FF, Chrome, IESpell, etc. but this one is the client's request.

Given that the only way to implement something like this (real time) is with JavaScript libraries, I want to know has anyone tried any of the open source ones?  Were they any good?  In general, what types of good/bad things can be said about this approach?

I guess going into this, I am against it as it is just more work for the end users's machine to do for little benefit.  I guess what I mean by that is that it will be a script that is constantly doing something as opposed to an AJAX request or a quick div update which could lead to seemingly bad performance for our application even though it is a spell checker checking every input field on the page.  It seems also that there is lots of room for a javascript error to stall the entire site.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that a spell-checker should be native if it's running at all times. If the client demands an explicit spell checker, though, it should be implemented as a button to be clicked when needed. It might also be worth firing that XHR request after the user has stopped typing for a certain amount of time, like SO does for syntax highlighting when writing a post.

I used [After the Deadline](http://www.afterthedeadline.com/) for my school newspaper's back-end spell-checker, since it is powerful, checked for simple grammar errors as well, and [integrated easily with TinyMCE](http://www.afterthedeadline.com/download.slp?platform=TinyMCE). There's also a [jQuery plugin](http://www.afterthedeadline.com/download.slp?platform=jQuery) to integrate with the service.

Comment: Both of those a good ideas.  Perhaps I could tie the spell check to the submit() of the form.  Then the user could choose to correct or nor correct.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

I've done some research on this problem for a web application that I am planning.

[Googie Spell](http://orangoo.com/labs/GoogieSpell/) is very good, you can use their servers or run your own [python backend](http://orangoo.com/labs/GoogieSpell/Download/Nox_Spell_Server/).

There's a demo [here](http://orangoo.com/spellcheck/).

Comment: I like the way that the googie spell looks.  I may end up using the ideas of the above with your recommendation.