# Need Client side spell checker for DIV

Tags: javascript, asp.net, spell-checking

I have content-editable div in my asp.net application.I am looking for client side spell checker(FREE) for this one.Does anyone knows which one i have to use.i already tried on Google some of the spellchecker but i didn't find specific for DIV.

i tried with this link [**Spell checker**](http://brandonaaron.net/code/spellcheck/demos) but it's not working in IE8(working in mozilla).

Can anybody tell me which one spell checker used by stack overflow.

**------------------------------P.S.----------------------------------------------**

I tried link given below

[**Spell checker link 1**](http://brandonaaron.net/code/spellcheck/demos)

[**Spell checker link 2**](http://ponderer.org/javascript/spell.html)

[**Spell checker link 3**](http://www.opencomponents.net/spellayt/demo/examples.htm)

**Its working perfectly in Mozilla but in IE8 on right click it doesn't display any suggestion.**

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript based spell-checkers for web applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506533/javascript-based-spell-checkers-for-web-applications)

Comment: I checked After the Deadline for jQuery (Spellcheck DIV Demonstration) but its not working correctly.Once u click on Spell check link it shows spelling mistakes with underline which is correct.but if u again click on this link it display alert message(No writing errors were found) but spelling mistake is there.

Comment: I am looking for free spell checker but Googie Spell is paid.

Answer (score 3):

You have several full js libraries that does spellcheck :

http://code.google.com/p/bjspell/