# How to highlight worng spelling on textbox?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

I would like to show wrong spelling on a textbox.
I not sure what to use , if it can be done with javascript,
or any other language to make it work.
I would like it to show wrong word red highlight.

Something like this:
http://foundeo.com/spell-checker/ but i wont need the 'check spelling' 
button.

Im trying to get it to work on IE 8, dont care about other browsers.

In this textbox I would like it to show the the wrong spelling words.

```
<p>
        Please provide specific comments about <strong>#GetEmployee.emp_namefirst#</strong>  to support your ratings:

        <br>
        <textarea style="width:99%;" rows="3" name="txtPosComment"></textarea></p>
```

Comment: is it anywhere online to see it?

Comment: (You have to wonder if the title was intentional....)

Comment: @MichaelTodd I do very much wonder that myself...

Comment: @michaeltodd i was hoping somebody would help this way ;)

Answer (score 0):

It could certainly be done using JavaScript, but you will likely need to communicate with a server as well. You're going to want to send words to the server and have the server check the spelling and then send a result back to the client. Otherwise you would need to send the entire dictionary to the client (which I guess is feasible if it's small, but for example, the entire English language could be a very large file).

You might also be able to hook into the spell check services of various browsers and operating systems using JavaScript, though I don't know how to go about that.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a similar question in the following link that might resolve your problem [Javascript based spell-checkers for web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506533/javascript-based-spell-checkers-for-web-applications)

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML5's SpellCheck attribute.

```
spellcheck="true"
```

It's got support in most modern browsers

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_spellcheck.asp

Examlple

```
<input type="text" spellcheck="true" />
```

Comment: This, ofcourse, would not stop the users from entering input that is misspelled, however it would help them not doing it intentionally